# How to set day of weeks for email reminder of Google Calendar Event object by java code?

Tags: android, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client

I want to set repeat email notification in Google calendar API v3. I create nofication:

```
        EventReminder reminder = new EventReminder();
        reminder.setMinutes(5);
        reminder.setMethod("email");

        Event.Reminders eRem = new Event.Reminders();
        List<EventReminder> reminders = new ArrayList<>();
        reminders.add(reminder);
        eRem.setOverrides(reminders);
        eRem.setUseDefault(false);

        event.setReminders(eRem);
```

It`s work fine, but I cant find solution to set repeat days for this notification. Have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The API only offers the `EventReminder.setMinutes()` method, but you could use [`TimeUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) to convert your number of days in minutes like so:

```
// Reminder in 2 days
reminder.setMinutes(TimeUnit.MINUTES.convert(2, TimeUnit.DAYS));
```